# brick chimney chips

Tags: brick, chimney

What could be reasons that a brick chimney outside of house chips off. So the bricks, chimney built of, chip off, large pieces fell off. Is it normal aging process, or low quality bricks/mortar something else ?

Recently I watched a few houses for sale, and few had this issue with chimneys, all had capped tops.

Thanks.

Comment: Does it have effloresence (white powdery surface), algea? how much water does it see and is the top sealed/capped properly? Is the crown cracked at all? Please add some pictures.

Comment: My son's house chimney was struck by lightning a few years back and his chimney is now doing the same thing. He had a chimney guy tell him that this is common with chimneys struck by lightning.

Comment: @noybman, I updated my question. Unfortunately I don't have pictures. What part of chimney is called crown?

Comment: Most likely the masonry cement cap or "wash" that tops off the chimney and covers the surface of the brick so rain/snow does not directly set in the top of the brick. It acts as a first deterrent from water infiltration.